# Trouble using UV4L raspidisp

Tags: uv4l, v4l2

I'm having trouble using the UV4L raspidisp device driver from [linux-projects](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/installation/). This is supposed to provide a V4L2 compliant device that provides the output from the Raspberry Pi's HDMI output at `/dev/videoX`.

Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. While the installation instruction on the page skips to mention that `uv4l-raspicam` is not optional even if I don't have a camera attached and also don't intend to do so, I can't get a frame capture using the V4L2 interface.

I also tried some configuration of the driver by issuing

```
uv4l --driver raspidisp --display 0 --framerate 5 --resolution 3
```

I am using this [bellbind/capture.c](https://gist.github.com/bellbind/6813905) for testing. It compiles with

```
gcc capture.c -ljpeg -o capture
```

So, as opposed to the suggested compile statement you just skip `-std=c99`. This code works flawlessly with a UVC webcam, but not with UV4L raspidisp. I get an `Operation not permitted` error, even when I run the software with `sudo`.

What am I missing here? Has anyone already worked with UV4L raspidisp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raspicam` driver **is** optional. That said, you are missing `--auto-video_nr` in your command line to create the `/dev/video0` node expected by your program:

`sudo killall uv4l` (in case some other instances are running, e.g. `raspicam` - however, this is optional, as multiple instances can run simultaneously)

```
uv4l --driver raspidisp --display 0 --framerate 5 --resolution 3 --auto-video_nr
```

The `capture.c` program does not support the `YUV420P` format provided by the driver. It asks for `YUYV` instead and does not check the answer from the driver which returns `YUV420P`, as said. So it ends up with producing a `result.jpg` showing some garbage from the display. The program should be fixed to handle `YUV420P`.

Comment: I also had the `raspidisp-extras` to get a video device on reboot. Those seem to do nothing unless `raspicam` is also installed. Now I removed both an with the command you posted here it works like a charm. I know the program needs adaption but that is something I can handle. I can see that the device returns a "YU12" image in the V4L2 terminology. A device that I could not open even it was present, was something I have struggled with for quite a bit. Thank you!

Comment: You are right in saying there is a problem with the raspidisp-extras package (which should automatically load the raspidisp driver at boot). I checked the systemd .service file in it and noticed there is a typo: "raspicam" instead of "raspidisp". I sent an email to linux-projects.org and asked them to fix the problem. They ack.'ed and I can see the fix online, Try to update the packages.

Comment: I tried the updated package on a fresh raspbian stretch. Now the device appears as /dev/video1 but it does not work as expected. I get the error `Software caused connection abort` when calling `VIDIOC_QUERYBUF`. But it works if I remove `--mem-lock` from `uv4l_raspidisp.service`.

Comment: weird. I have no problems on my side with the installed .service.

Comment: Mystery solved. I set the memory split to 128 on a Raspberry Pi Model A (256 MB RAM in total). Obviously the remaining free memory is not enough. I get random errors like the above, sudden termination of the SSH session and kernel panics, stating "Out of memory and no killable processes...". But works fine without `--mem-lock`.